# Conversion of max_score field in elasticsearch to a percentage

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch, search, kibana

Is there any algorithm that converts the max_score of a search made in elasticsearch to a percentage score?Please suggest some idea to do that.

Comment: Not that I know of. Can you elaborate on the use case? Why not post-process it after the query resolves?

Comment: Use case is basically to resolve the issue of zero hits in the search results, for that I have made a custom analyzer and also made use of synonym filter in it,

Comment: I have to compare two different queries, one that i have written and other written already by someone else . In both case,Use case is basically to resolve the issue of zero hits in the search results, for that I hv made a custom analyzer nd also made use of synonym filter in it: ``` "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 18,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.7050395, ```   this result is i m getting on making a query to the document

Comment: How can I post process it after query resolves? any idea for that.?

Comment: I actually want to make my max_score more represantable in the form of percentage so that i can make comparison, but i cannot find any idea to convert it to percentage and need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The score values (plus the resulting `max_score`) are arbitrary and don't necessarily need to be (nor usually are) in the interval 0 <= x <= 1. A score could easily be `420` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

With that being said, in order to calculate the percentages, you need a denominator. The max score of `2.7050` from your example can be treated as 2.7% but also as 0.27% if scores from other queries are in the hundreds-range and your denominator is 1000.

So what I meant by post-processing is that when you get a response from ES to wherever you're running your query from (backend/frontend/...), you need to know you denominator and can only then determine the percentage. There's no reasonable need for such functionality to exist directly in ES.

Comment: What field should I look for denominator? should i look for number of documents being returned after running the search query?

Comment: Is there any other way with which I can get the similarity score in terms of percentage? A percentage which I can use to represent how well my query is working as compared to other existing query for the same use case?

Comment: Just like we do in comparison of ML models in terms of accuracy percentage....here I want a method to show my document similarity score as percentage.